# how to do exact match in elastic search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack

I want to find exact match .if there is no match .I don't want to **null**.

I am search this id `6a8c283f-1e75-ec11-8943-000d3a15f525`.
it is giving me this output

- **fcf0dd4e-abbc-ec11-983f-0022482588e9**

But these it is not matched only `ec11` matched

I tried this search query

```
 result = await client.search({
          index: 'products',
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "sysid":sysid
            }
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because your `sysid` field is of type `text` and is thus analyzed at indexing time and tokenized into `fcf0dd4e`, `abbc`, `ec11`, `8943` and `000d3a15f525`.

Also when searching using a match query, the searched term is analyzed as well into the following tokens `6a8c283f`, `1e75`, `ec11`, `8943`, `000d3a15f525`.

As you saw, the match works because `ec11` matches.

For an exact match, what you need to do is to run your query against a `keyword` field instead. Maybe you're lucky and your mapping already contains a `sysid.keyword` sub-field. If not, you need to change your mapping and reindex your data.

Then you'll be able to run your `term` query like this and get your exact match:

```
  "term": {
     "sysid.keyword":sysid
  }
```

Comment: if possible can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882267/how-to-search-in-two-column-in-elastic/71882722#71882722

Comment: It's the same issue as in this question. The problem is your `sysid` field. Can you share your mapping, i.e. what you get from `GET products`